# Changing table name in SQLite3 using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 database and I changed a table called `People` to `Persons` (to better match the standard of having a singular `Person` model).

I made this change manually in the database using SQLite3 and the call:

```
ALTER TABLE People RENAME TO Persons;
```

Now when I run the app I get an error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: people: SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
```

I changed the table name in the controller, model, migration and schema files to match the change. Where else should I make the change?

Comment: `people` is the right word to use. Why would you use `persons`?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the table name, then Rails' default convention is broken. You have to tell Rails to use the `persons` table instead of `people` because Rails thought the table for `Person` model is `people`.

```
[1] pry(main)> 'person'.pluralize
=> "people"
```

If you still want to change the table name, then you need to config it like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "persons"
end
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Sorry for the trivial question. Still getting used to Rails.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be better generating a model "person" and letting Rails handle the pluralization. It probably converts to people and is getting confused.

You would then migrate data over and then drop your old table. You would have to check the naming for your views and controllers also.

Comment: Yeah I guess rails was using a bit of magic when it originally was fine with People. Should have just stuck with that. But I did solve this issue. Thanks!